# Default constructor value for bool type

Tags: c++, default-value, boolean

Which value does the default constructor of the bool type return in C++?

For instance, writing

```
int i = int();
```

guarantees that the variable **i** will be initiated always with 0.

I guess such an initialization routine is possible as well:

```
bool b = bool();
```

But unfortunately I could not find anywhere which value such a default bool constructor is defined to return. Is the variable **b** always initialized with **false** or **true**.

Comment: yOU could have written two lines of code to find out by printing the value!

Comment: Please see the comment of Alexandre C. to Prasoon Saurav's answer below, to know the reason why I have not tested it with a specific compiler.

Comment: could you please give a proof for your statement about int?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`false`.

Seen in the C++14 draft N4296, section 8.5 (Initializers), paragraph 6, list item 1 and references therein, and paragraph 8, list item 4.

Comment: I've +1'ed this one, because it's the oldest answer that correctly gives a boolean value as the result. Confusing "zero" with "false" is widely common in C++. :(

Comment: Reference please! What you say may be the truth, but how can one _know_ that?

Comment: PLEASE give a link to the standard where this is declared, because MSVC 2013 defaults a bool to TRUE.

Comment: @ThE_-_BliZZarD: Default-initialization of bools amounts to zero-initialization. Are you sure you are not doing `bool b;` or `struct F { bool b; };`, where in both cases `b` never gets initialized ?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb What do you mean "confusing zero with false"? AFAIK false = 0 and true = 1, though I guess it could be implementation-defined—but what implementation would do that? It would break countless programs.

Answer (score 7):

bool is an integral type, and value-intialization should make it zero.

Comment: +1: integral types don't have a constructor in C or C++, that's a Java-ism.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the variable b always initialized with false or true?

**false**

Converting `true` to an `integer` type will yield `1`, and converting `false` will yield `0` (`4.5/4` and `4.7/4`)

A very simple test code

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
  bool b=bool();

  if(!b)
  {
     std::cout<<"b: false";
  }

}
```

Comment: C++ is full of "undefined behavior" things which make such experimentation dangerous.

Comment: Why do you think the behavior of the above code is undefined?

Comment: it isn't, by your quoting of the Holy Standard. But one should not get confidence that something is standard by making it work on its own machine.

Comment: @Alexandre C: I fully agree. This kind of test code is just wrong.

Comment: @DeadMG: the answer had been edited to avoid misleading readers though.

Comment: @DeadMG: I don't understand what are you trying to say, be more specific.

Comment: wat is undefined behavior?

Comment: 1. Did you tried in debug or release?  
2. Could you made stack dirty with -1 before creating new variable? Because it is undefined.  
3. How this lines of standard points that default constructor for bool initializes it with 0?

Answer (score 1):

The b is initialized also with zero.

Answer (score 1):

bool behaves 'as if it were declared':

```
enum bool {false,true};
```

It is an integral type and might be casted to int as values 0 and 1 (respectively), and its default value is false.