# C++14: Default values in tuple when returning {}

Tags: c++, c++14, stdtuple

Consider:

```
std::tuple<bool, double, int> getTuple()
{
    return {};
}
```

What does the standard say about the values in the resulting tuple in this case? Is it guaranteed that e.g. the bool is always false?

Comment: I'm going to guess yes, because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3308028/10957435), but that is assuming tuples use default constructors like this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default constructor of `tuple` is specified to value-initialize all elements, see case 1 in [cppreference link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple).

In brief, value-initialization is the same as if the element were initialized by `{}` (there are corner cases I'm omitting). For primitive types this means `bool` is `false`, `double` is `0.0` and `int` is `0` .